# Activex doesn't work with apache balancer

Tags: apache, load-balancing, activex-exe

I'm having a problem to run and exe from my browser using ActiveX.

I have Apache balancer and 4 ManagedServer on Weblogic.

The problem is:

Browser---> ServerA IT WORKS open my exe

Browser---> Apache-Balancer---> Server(A,B,C,D) random server DOESN'T WORK my exe doens,t run.

Any help?
Thanks
Carlo

Comment: Do you have any error messages?

Comment: I have checked the Apache logs but no error is coming up, from the browser I don't know how I have to use IE and I don't know how get the javascript console.

Comment: Sorry I did a mistake on the explanation of my issue. Please read again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using proxy balancer for load balancing? There might be possibility that session stickiness is not working .Try to configure Apache and weblogic using wls web server proxy plugin for apache which is designed for weblogic load balancing and by default having session stickiness enabled.

Check below link

```
Http://Middlewaresnippets.blogspot.in/2015/05/working-with-apache-http-server.html
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I figured out the the issue was on "Compatibility View setting" in I.E. Defined from my company.

The pop up(jsp) that contains the Javascript and the ActiveX command doesn't respect the control defined internally in my company.

The fix was to add and put the Javascript into head tag as is recommender.

In test it works anyway because there wasn't defined those restriction